# copy select data from one sheet to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I am new to creating macros in Excel, and I am in a difficult position.  I have a woorksheet of 48 columns and 6000+ rows. I have to retrieve select data from 20 columns and all rows, and place them into table of 3 columns and equal number of rows. For example Copy Sheet1: A2, E1, E3 and Paste into New Sheet3: A2, B2, C2. Needs to be automated due to size of spreadsheet, and the fact that the data is not formatted to be copied directly

I received an error 424 (Object Needed) using the following script.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 3
Counter_H = 2
Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER_LEAK_REPAIRS_CY2012").Cells(Counter, 4).Value     = " "
thisworkbooks.Sheets("Sheet1").Select("A" & Counter, "B" & Counter, "C" &      Counter).Value = thisworkbooks.Sheets("MASTER_LEAK_REPAIRS_CY2012").Select("D" & Counter, "Q" & (Counter - Counter_H), "Q" & Counter).Value
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Counter_H = Counter + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Please help me.

Comment: change `thisworkbooks` into `ThisWorkbook`... do it twice!

Comment: this sounds doable with VLOOKUP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer, based on below comment.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 3
Counter_H = 2

Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER_LEAK_REPAIRS_CY2012").Cells(Counter, 4).Value = ""
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Counter) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER_LEAK_REPAIRS_CY2012").Range("D" & Counter)    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Counter) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER_LEAK_REPAIRS_CY2012").Range("Q" & (Counter - Counter_H)) 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Counter) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER_LEAK_REPAIRS_CY2012").Range("Q" & Counter)
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Counter_H = Counter + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

When I tried you original, I received error 450, but with this I did not.

Let me know if you have any problems!

Comment: Just for your knowledge- changing from `Do...Loop` to `While...Wend` isn't a good direction as `While...Wend` is old-fashioned type of loop with some disadvantages (like you can't use anything like `Exit Do`). Will work but try to avoid...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Matt. I did try it and received an error 450. I modified to test on a smaller spreadsheet, but it did not run. Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim Counter As Integer
   Dim Counter_H As Integer

  Counter = 3
  Counter_H = 2

  Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Students").Cells(Counter, 4).Value = ""
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select("A" & Counter, "B" & Counter, "C" & Counter).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Students").Select("A" & Counter, "C" & (Counter - Counter_H), "C" & Counter).Value
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Counter_H = Counter + 1
  Loop
  End Sub

Comment: Yes thank you so much. It saved my summer internship. :-)  Very grateful.